# Python - skip outofbounds exceptions for the sake of clarity?

Tags: python

Suppose you have to accomplish this quite generic task:

> Given a string, we'll say that the
>   front is the first 3 chars of the
>   string. If the string length is less
>   than 3, the front is whatever is
>   there. Return a new string which is 3
>   copies of the front.

Now, as Python lists silently skip out of bounds exceptions, one solution could be:

```
def front(string):
  return 3 * string[:3]
```

This works even if the given string's length is less than length 3. But is this good practice?

Comment: Python lists do *not* silently skip out of bounds exception. `string[3]` will raise `IndexError` if `len(string)==3`. Only when slicing lists are you allowed to go across bounds, and I doubt that there happens any exception at all that would need to be "silenced".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly a good practice, if your requirement is exactly that. :)

```
    return 3 * string[:3]
```

Comment: +1 for "if your requirement is exactly that". That statement works on som many levels :)

Comment: But doesn't it produce a costly exception underneath? I'm coming from a Java background, there this would be really bad practice... on the other hand, they have very different philosophies :-).

Comment: I don't know why it is bad practice Java, but it is falling in definition as how list slices can be used in Python. When you omit the lower bound, it is the start, if you omit the upper bound, it is length of list and by definition/design if the upper bound is greater than length, it is truncated to the length.This design also helpful for Python as allows negative list indexes. (BTW, you don't need to check if condition in my answer too. Just reverting to previous version)

Comment: Even if this did produce an exception, Pythonic code generally follows the "it is better to ask for forgiveness than permission" philosophy.